# Is it possible to set different VAT rate per Shipping Zone in Opencart?

Tags: opencart

I'm doing some research among some e-commerce platforms and I'd like to know if there is a way to set a different VAT rate per Shipping Zone in Opencart depending on if the order requires an invoice.

My test case scenario is the following:

Area A has 23% VAT for retail customers, 16% for wholesale customers (invoice).
Area B has 23% VAT for retail customers, 23% for wholesale customers (invoice).

For an order that requires an invoice and billing address is in Area A I need the order amounts to be analyzed according to the 16% VAT rate in the final step of the order.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart allows you to set up "GeoZones" which are groupings of areas. These can be assigned to different vat rates and applied based on the customers location, so in answer to your question yes OpenCart can achieve this (see `SYSTEM > LOCALISATION > TAXES > TAX RATES` in the admin menu where you can see how geozones are applied to them)

Comment: Many thanks, once I've tested this I'll get back to your answer.